# pyyaml: dumping without tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.dump(u'abc')
"!!python/unicode 'abc'\n"
```

But I want

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.dump(u'abc', magic='something')
'abc\n'
```

What magic param forces no tagging?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use `safe_dump` instead of `dump`. Just keep in mind that it won't be able to represent arbitrary Python objects then. Also, when you `load` the YAML, you will get a `str` object instead of `unicode`.

Comment: safe_dump seems to force a '...' at the end, but that's easy to fix

Comment: @ATOzTOA I'm not sure what you're asking, but there's `safe_dump_all` as well.

Comment: @interjay Yeah, right. I tried that, but I have a object, not a string. Makes sense.

Comment: `safe_dump` doesn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 19):

How about this:

```
def unicode_representer(dumper, uni):
    node = yaml.ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value=uni)
    return node

yaml.add_representer(unicode, unicode_representer)
```

This seems to make dumping unicode objects work the same as dumping str objects for me (Python 2.6).

```
In [72]: yaml.dump(u'abc')
Out[72]: 'abc\n...\n'

In [73]: yaml.dump('abc')
Out[73]: 'abc\n...\n'

In [75]: yaml.dump(['abc'])
Out[75]: '[abc]\n'

In [76]: yaml.dump([u'abc'])
Out[76]: '[abc]\n'
```

Comment: This works for basic cases, but messes up the data in some cases. Also, you should mention in the answer that the function is called on `yaml` and not on an object.

Answer (score 4):

You need a new dumper class that does everything the standard Dumper class does but overrides the representers for str and unicode.

```
from yaml.dumper import Dumper
from yaml.representer import SafeRepresenter

class KludgeDumper(Dumper):
   pass

KludgeDumper.add_representer(str,
       SafeRepresenter.represent_str)

KludgeDumper.add_representer(unicode,
        SafeRepresenter.represent_unicode)
```

Which leads to

```
>>> print yaml.dump([u'abc',u'abc\xe7'],Dumper=KludgeDumper)
[abc, "abc\xE7"]

>>> print yaml.dump([u'abc',u'abc\xe7'],Dumper=KludgeDumper,encoding=None)
[abc, "abc\xE7"]
```

Granted, I'm still stumped on how to keep this pretty.

```
>>> print u'abc\xe7'
abcç
```

And it breaks a later yaml.load()

```
>>> yy=yaml.load(yaml.dump(['abc','abc\xe7'],Dumper=KludgeDumper,encoding=None))
>>> yy
['abc', 'abc\xe7']
>>> print yy[1]
abc�
>>> print u'abc\xe7'
abcç
```

Answer (score 2):

little addition to interjay's excellent answer, you can keep your unicode on a reload if you take care of your file encodings.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import yaml
import codecs

data = dict(key = u"abcç\U0001F511")

fn = "test2.yaml"
with codecs.open(fn, "w", encoding="utf-8") as fo:
    yaml.safe_dump(data, fo)

with codecs.open(fn, encoding="utf-8") as fi:
    data2 = yaml.safe_load(fi)

print ("data2:", data2, "type(data.key):", type(data2.get("key")) )

print data2.get("key")
```

*test2.yaml* contents in my editor:

`{key: "abc\xE7\uD83D\uDD11"}`

print outputs:

`('data2:', {'key': u'abc\xe7\U0001f511'}, 'type(data.key):', <type 'unicode'>)
abcç`

Plus, after reading http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/war_is_peace.html I am pretty sure that safe_load/safe_dump is where I want to be anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started with Python and YAML, but probably this may also help. Just compare outputs:

```
def test_dump(self):
    print yaml.dump([{'name': 'value'}, {'name2': 1}], explicit_start=True)
    print yaml.dump_all([{'name': 'value'}, {'name2': 1}])
```