# pyyaml is producing undesired !!python/unicode output

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am using pyyaml to dump an object to a file. There are several unicode strings in the object. I've done this before, but now it's producing output items like this:

```
'item': !!python/unicode "some string"
```

Instead of the desired:

```
'item': 'some string'
```

I'm intending to output as utf-8. The current command I use is:

```
yaml.dump(data,file(suite_out,'w'),encoding='utf-8',indent=4,allow_unicode=True)
```

In other locations I do the following and it works:

```
codecs.open(suite_out,"w","utf-8").write(
    yaml.dump(suite,indent=4,width=10000)
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Python 2.7.3*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950306/pyyaml-dumping-without-tags

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I tried many combinations and the only one I can find that consistently produces the correct YAML output is:

```
yaml.safe_dump(data, file(filename,'w'), encoding='utf-8', allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: This seems to just generate `!!python/str` tags instead of `!!python/unicode` tags.

Comment: slightly adapted for Python 3.6, it works just fine: `yaml.safe_dump({"key" : "foo"}, open("test3.out",'w'), allow_unicode=True)`  the encoding doesn't seem necessary, probably because of the default text file encodings in Python3, but without `allow_unicode` you get `"foo\U0001F9E8"` in the file.
`

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the accepted answer, that `safe_dump` can produce the expected result, I checked the source of `python2.7/site-packages/yaml/representer.py`, and found that the `Representer` for `dump` and `safe_dump` are using different represent functions for `unicode`.

And the represent function can be overwritten with `add_representer`. So you can just get the represent function from the `SafeRepresenter`, and register it to be used in `dump`.

I have to do this as I have some custom types, so I cannot use `safe_dump`.

The code is as following:

```py
def represent_unicode(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data)
yaml.add_representer(unicode, represent_unicode)
```

My command to produce the output:

```py
yaml.dump(yml, encoding='utf-8', allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True)
```

python version is 2.7.5, PyYMAL is 3.10.