# pyyam safe_dump doesn't work to get rid of tags

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, yaml, tags, pyyaml

Based on answers to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950306/pyyaml-dumping-without-tags), I should use `safe_dump` instead of `dump` to get rid of undesired tags like `!!python/unicode` but it dosn't work for me.

In my personal case, the undesired tag is `!!python/object:module_example.items.ExampleItem` and also a dict key `_values` is added. All of that maybe because I'm using scrapy and my `item` dict is created through the ExampleItem class.

Here is the code:

```
import yaml

yaml.dump({'obj': item}, outfile)
# using safe_dump gives an empty output
```

The current output:

```
obj: !!python/object:module_example.items.ExampleItem
  _values:
    first_name: 'foo'
    last_name: 'bar'
```

The desired output:

```
obj:
  first_name: 'foo'
  last_name: 'bar'
```

How to get rid of those tags ?

Comment: Please show your code. With Python3, you shouldn't ever get `!!python/unicode`.

Comment: @flyx I edited the question to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

An important aspect of PyYAML is that you communicate your intent via the types of the values you give to `dump()`: If you give only *dict*, *list* and *str* values, you will get a standard YAML output without tags. If you give something else, like a class instance of `ExampleItem`, you're telling PyYAML „I want this structure to recreate an `ExampleItem` object when I'm loading it again“. This is why PyYAML adds the tag. Understand that an instance of `ExampleItem` is *not* a dict.

`safe_dump()` restricts the types you can give: It only accepts types known to the `SafeDumper` (which you can extend). Since you didn't tell it about `ExampleItem`, it fails.

If your goal is to *not* have any information about your types in the output, don't give values of non-standard types – give only `dict`, `list` and `str`. For example, you can simply do

```
yaml.dump({"obj": item.__dict__}, outfile)
```

However, this solution doesn't work as soon as `item` contains more non-standard type instances. The more general approach is to register custom representers:

```py
def clean_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping(
            yaml.resolver.BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG, data.__dict__)

yaml.add_representer(ExampleItem, clean_representer)

print(yaml.dump({"obj": item}))
```

You can use the same `clean_representer` for every class that can occur. By setting the tag to `DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG` (which is `!!map` as specified by the spec), you allow the PyYAML emitter to omit the tag.

Alternatively, just don't use custom class instances in the call to `yaml.dump()`. Whether this is possible depends of course on your code; but if you only build up a data structure to dump it to YAML, it makes no sense to use custom classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Effectively it was a type issue, replacing `item` by `dict(item)` solved it.